# tensorflow calculations without retraining

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to train a model once in tensorflow, and then want to use the trained model for predicting some functions. Before we get into specifics, lets define a couple of functions ...

```
def runTF(func, inpDict):
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    result = sess.run(func, feed_dict = inpDict)
    sess.close()
    return result
```

and

```
def optTF(opt, res, others, inpDict, nSteps, printSteps=50):

    os, re = [], []

    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(nSteps):

        # First run the optimizer ...
        sess.run(opt, feed_dict = inpDict)

        # Save all the data you want to save
        temp = sess.run( [res] + others, feed_dict = inpDict) 
        re.append(temp[0])
        os.append(temp[1:])

        if (i%printSteps) == 0:
            print('{:5d}'.format(i))

    sess.close()

    return re, os
```

Here are a couple of steps for what I am doing ...

A. Generating some data

```
N        = 500
features = 2
nSteps   = 1000

X = np.array([np.random.random(N), np.random.random(N)])
data = [X.T, X[0].reshape(-1, 1)]
```

B. create a simple linear model

```
d    = tf.placeholder(shape = np.shape(data[0]), dtype = tf.float32, name='d') # input layer
dOut = tf.placeholder(shape = np.shape(data[1]), dtype = tf.float32, name='dOut') # output layer

W = tf.Variable(  np.random.randn(features, 1), dtype = tf.float32, name='W')
b = tf.Variable(               np.zeros((1,1)), dtype = tf.float32, name='b')

result = tf.matmul(d, W)+b
cost = tf.reduce_mean((dOut - result)**2)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.1).minimize(cost)
```

C. Lets run the optimiser

```
inpDict = {d: data[0], dOut:data[1]}
ot = optTF(optimizer, result, [W, cost], inpDict, 200, 50)
```

Here, I have checked the result, and see that it is what I want. So the optimiser is working fine. The model has been optimised. Now, I want to make a prediction with some other data. So I do ...

```
r = runTF(result, inpDict)
```

This new result is not what I would expect from the same trained model.

Now, as long as I stay within the same `tf.Session()`, we are ok. However, I do want to be able to do predictions even when I an done with a session. So my question is, how do I use a model once we have trained it in one session in a different session?

Note, the entire thing is something that I did in a different session?

**Edited:**

I edited the two functions to incorporate the saving  ...

```
def runTF(func, inpDict, modelFile=None):

    if modelFile is not None:
        saver = tf.train.Saver()

    sess = tf.Session()

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    if modelFile is not None:
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(modelFile)
        print(modelFile, ckpt)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            print('Session restored')

    result = sess.run(func, feed_dict = inpDict)
    sess.close()
    return result
```

and

```
def optTF(opt, res, others, inpDict, nSteps, printSteps=50, modelFile='models/temp.ckpt'):

    os, re = [], []
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(nSteps):

        # First run the optimizer ...
        sess.run(opt, feed_dict = inpDict)

        # Save all the data you want to save
        temp = sess.run( [res] + others, feed_dict = inpDict) 
        re.append(temp[0])
        os.append(temp[1:])

        if (i%printSteps) == 0:
            print('{:5d}'.format(i))

    path = saver.save(sess, modelFile)
    print('Model saved in: {}'.format(path))
    sess.close()

    return re, os
```

And running the model as:

```
ot = optTF(optimizer, result, [cost]+weights+biases, inpDict, 200, 50)
r = runTF([result], inpDict, 'models/temp.ckpt')
```

Still nothing! I checked that:

- The value of `ckpt` is `None`
- The models folder has the following files:

  - checkpoint
  - temp.ckpt.index
  - temp.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
  - temp.ckpt.meta

Answer (score 0):

You need to save and restore the session you are creating and training. As in

```python
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    if restore:
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(save_path)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    else:
        # ... training code omitted ...
        saver.save(sess, save_path)
```

checkout also https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model if you want to create a full model with `estimator` instead of just one session.

Comment: Thanks @andresbravog. I did try saving the state like you mentioned. I have edited my answer. Please see above